# Rand order in stock SQL Woocommerce

Tags: sql, wordpress, random, woocommerce

I have these 2 codes, currently it runs randomly but it does not filter the products in stock.
How would it be to be random and respect woocommerce "instock" products?

Code1:`$sortQuery = 'ORDER BY RAND()';`

Code 2: `$sortQuery = ' AND id NOT IN (SELECT post_id FROM`'.FSwpTable('feeds')."`WHERE schedule_id='" . (int)$scheduleId . "') ORDER BY RAND()";`

I have understood that the stock is stored here

> meta_value = _stock_status WHERE meta_key = 'instock';

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may need to tweak this a bit as I don't have a WP database in front of me at the moment, but I believe you want an SQL query as such

```
SELECT wp_postmeta.post_id 
FROM wp_postmeta 
INNER JOIN wp_posts ON wp_posts.Id = wp_postmeta.post_id 
WHERE wp_post.meta_key = 'instock'
ORDER BY RAND();
```